# Visual Basic: How do I make a Global List of a custom Class?

Tags: vb.net, class, object, global

I think I'm missing an important idiosyncrasy of Visual Basic. I mostly just know C++, so I don't understand the need for the Dim keyword, and the As New keyword. However, I am familiar with the New keyboard in C++, which is used when you use a pointer.

So in Visual Basic are all variables pointers? What's going on here?

I want to make a custom Class. And have a list or array of say, four of them, and for them to be Globally accessible all throughout my program. Do I declare them in my Form Class? My program is just the one Form.

Ok, so I've got the list to exist, but only in the button click sub routine.
How do I make my List of Clocks Global?

```
    Public Class MyClock
        Public elapsedtime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        Public active As Boolean
        Public Sub New()
            elapsedtime = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        End Sub
        Public Function Display()
            Return elapsedtime.ToString
        End Function


        Public Sub Start()
            active = True
        End Sub
        Public Sub Stopclock()
            active = False
        End Sub
        Public Sub Toggle()
            If (active = True) Then
                active = False
                Stopclock()
            Else
                active = True
                Start()
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class Form1
        Dim ticincrement As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100)

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            Dim ClockList As New List(Of MyClock)()
            ClockList.Add(New MyClock)
            ClockList.Add(New MyClock)
            ClockList.Add(New MyClock)
            ClockList.Add(New MyClock)


            Console.WriteLine(ClockList.Count)
            Console.WriteLine(ClockList(0).elapsedtime)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: Please be careful when tagging and ***READ*** the tag information. VBA is ***NOT*** vb.net - it's something quite different. If this kind of question is directed to VBA you'll likely not get any useful kind of answer. I've corrected it for you - this time.

Comment: Declare the variable at the *class level* of the appropriate class... MyClock, I suppose, looking at the code in the question. And why are there two Form1 classes in the code? You might want to review the concept [mcve] when asking for help here...

Comment: The `Dim` keyword is just used to declare a variable when you don't explicitly specify an access modifier. If an access modifier is specified then `Dim` can be omitted, for instance: `Public myVar As Integer = 5`.

Comment: _"So in Visual Basic are all variables pointers?"_ - Yes and no. All reference types (classes) are internally accessed via their reference pointer, however this is _not_ the point of the `New` keyword. The `New` keyword in .NET initializes a _new instance_ of the specified class or structure and calls its constructor. So you basically use it whenever you need a new instance of an object. In C++ I think this would roughly be the equivalent to `MyCustomClass someVar(param1, param2);`

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you can use a [Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the “new” keyword is just a short cut that allows you to declare the variable (it is a pointer) and create + initialize an instance of the class being assigned to that variable.

The  following two are same.

```
Dim TestClock   as MyClock

TestClock = New MyClock
```

And

```
Dim TestClock   as New MyClock.
```

However, ONE very significant difference in the above two code snips should be noted:

In the 2nd example in which we declare using “new”, the new instance of the object (class) is thus created.

Often, we want to control WHEN the instance of the class (and  the new (initialize) event of the class will run. (So don’t use new in the var define).

The other issue of that WHEN you leave out the NEW keyword, then the class variable is essentially a pointer to the class, but one that does not yet exist.

Eg this:

```
    Dim pbar1 As New Pbar

    Dim pbar2 As Pbar

    pbar2 = pbar1
```

So, pbar2 we NEVER created an instance of the class, so it really is a pointer. So, from any code that follows, I can use pbar1, or pbar2 – they are pointing to and are the same instance of the one class we created with “new”.

This concept is important, since say if you going to pass a class to another form, then you could/would declare the class without new keyword as global scoped to that form.

Note that you should declare the variable as “public” if you want other forms/code to use that variable.

Eg:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Dim MyPbar As Pbar


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Etc. etc.
```

And if public global, we would use:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Public MyPbar As Pbar   <--- pubic scope - can use outside of form


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

Etc. etc.

Now

Then “any” place else in the project, you can go:

```
    Form1.MyPbar.Min = 1

    Form1.MyPbar.Max = 10
```

So, declaring as “public” will give you global scope. But you STILL must qualify the var by the form that variable resides in.

However, the scope is still limited to form that MUST be open. If that form is closed or goes out of scope, then of course you can’t reference that form in other forms/code.

## What amount “many” forms, and wanting true global scope var?

A number of ways exist, but most easy is to add a standard code module to your project. So add a "module" as opposed to a "class". In that standard code module, you can place common routines (functions/subs) that you want for the whole application. So this approach is nice, since you don’t have to create an instance of that code module (it not consider class). It is just a standard “library” of code where you can shove in a bunch of routines. This is a carryover idea and concept from VB6, or VBA, but it really is nice.

And any public var declared in such modules are scoped appcation wide global.

(If using “dim”, then scope is only to that module).

So, if we add a code module we get this:

```
Module Module1

    Public GlobalPbar As New Pbar

    Public Sub Test()

        MsgBox("test")

    End Sub

End Module
```

So in place of “dim” I used “public” since I want use of this var outside of “module1”.

So for global scoped functions, subs and variables (including pointers to class vars)?

Simply create (add) to your project a standard code module. Some even often create/add a code module called MyGlobals, and they don’t even place any sub/functions, but just a list of “public” variables which of course become scoped to the whole application.

So in summary:
Declaring a class var without “new” creates a pointer to an instance of a given class. (And in this case the pointer is nothing - the object  does not exist yet)

You can assign an existing instance of a class to the above declared variable – it works like a pointer. You have to use the new keyword in code to create that instance.

You can also for convenience sake combine the two above steps into one declare with the "new" keyword. This is often done, and of course with “overloading”, we can supply parameters when you do this.

You can create a global var in the standard code module. You can also create the “list of” variable in that code module, and it again will also be global scoped and not tied to one form, and you not be tied or limited to any instance of a form being open to use such global vars. And you don't have to qualify the sub or vars with module1, they are scoped global.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations are in-line.

```vb
Public Class Form2

    Private ClockList As New List(Of MyClock) 'This can be seen anywhere in the Form code.

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Add items to list with and without setting properties
        ClockList.Add(New MyClock(New TimeSpan(1, 13, 22, 7), True))
        ClockList.Add(New MyClock)
        ClockList.Add(New MyClock(New TimeSpan(0, 11, 3, 6), False))
        ClockList.Add(New MyClock(New TimeSpan(3, 7, 11, 433), True))
        Debug.Print(ClockList.Count.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(ClockList(0))
        'The default properties will print for the second item in the list
        Console.WriteLine(ClockList(1))
        Console.WriteLine(ClockList(2))
        Console.WriteLine(ClockList(3))
        Console.WriteLine("Values for the second item in list after properties set")
        'Setting properties of the second item in list
        ClockList(1).active = False
        ClockList(1).elapsedtime = New TimeSpan(14, 7, 22, 34)
        Console.WriteLine(ClockList(1))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyClock

    'TimeSpan(days,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds)
    'There is no need to set default values for the TimeSpan or call New
    'The TimeSpan is a Structure made up of Integers so the default values 
    'are automatically set
    Public Property elapsedtime As TimeSpan
    Public Property active As Boolean

    Public Sub New() 'Add back the default constructor
        'unnecessary to assign elapsedTime because it is already set to (0,0,0,0,0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ETime As TimeSpan, act As Boolean)
        elapsedtime = ETime
        active = act
    End Sub
    Public Function Display() As String
        Return elapsedtime.ToString
    End Function

    'Public Sub Start()
    '    active = True
    'End Sub
    'Public Sub Stopclock()
    '    active = False
    'End Sub
    Public Sub Toggle()
        active = Not active
        'If active = True Then
        '    active = False
        'You just set active to False, why would you call a Sub to set it to False?
        'Stopclock()
        'Else
        'active = True
        'You just set active to True, why would you call a Sub to set it to True?
        'Start()
        'End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"Elapsed Time is {elapsedtime.Days} Days, {elapsedtime.Hours} Hours, {elapsedtime.Minutes} Minutes, {elapsedtime.Seconds} Seconds, {elapsedtime.Milliseconds} Milliseconds and Active is {active}"
    End Function

End Class
```

Results displayed in Immediate Window

> 4
>
> Elapsed Time is 1 Days, 13 Hours, 22 Minutes, 7 Seconds, 0
>   Milliseconds and Active is True
>
> Elapsed Time is 0 Days, 0 Hours, 0 Minutes, 0 Seconds, 0 Milliseconds
>   and Active is False
>
> Elapsed Time is 0 Days, 11 Hours, 3 Minutes, 6 Seconds, 0 Milliseconds
>   and Active is False
>
> Elapsed Time is 3 Days, 7 Hours, 18 Minutes, 13 Seconds, 0
>   Milliseconds and Active is True
>
> Values for the second item in list after properties set
>
> Elapsed Time is 14 Days, 7 Hours, 22 Minutes, 34 Seconds, 0
>   Milliseconds and Active is False